# Scipy minimize SLSQP without constraints

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have an optimization problem with bounds and constraints as well. I'm using `scipy.optimize.minimize()` with the solver method `SLSQP` and well-defined bounds and constraints. With lots of troubles, the algorithm did not converge and always says `Iteration limit reached` even when I tried 15K iterations.

Today, I removed `constraint` and left everything else as is (I mean bounds). The algorithm converged and terminated successfully.

I don't know what happened.

I have two questions:

1. Is it sensible to run unconstraint optimization with bounds using `SLSQP`?
2. If that is sensible, then what is the intuition/interpretation of the result?